# How to verify XML Signature using CXF/JAXWS?

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, x509certificate, xml-signature, wsse

I am really having a hard time finding a tutorial that can validate an xml signature using cxf.

I have a signed xml request like this: **(NOTE: Signature value, digest value and X509 certificates are dummy values)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://namespaces.gsma.org/esim-messaging/1">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:Request>
            <ns:ParentNode>
                <ns:TobeSignedInfo>
                    <ns:id>010203</ns:id>
                    <ns:oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.31746</ns:oid>
                </ns:TobeSignedInfo>
                <ns:SampleAdditionalProperties>
                    <ns:Property key="myProperty" value="aValue"/>
                </ns:SampleAdditionalProperties>
                <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                        <ds:Reference URI="">
                            <ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            </ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                            <ds:DigestValue>rE7suDc1EdUOJx6auQsTp8kGfZEe+pq2zaDvsKDMc/A=</ds:DigestValue>
                        </ds:Reference>
                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:SignatureValue>
                        NXwOjw6ZT3NJRGqOluY8lF5/dkrTE89OjgB3z+kI4qmnTka0/hU6y9uihiRsrP+BZAMowhbwnPfy
                        ThEmTvMr0GGVB/w2pp0635Y8R672KNxZf2j48yFuz6ksyC5eBXVRAEswAt9lRh2ikcC9sULzLnSr
                        eA6rHNWiEm5v8OH708uZ/GWq4NlxQc8oLkrR634OY53ghPr2K+84vN99yxtGzYDHlTEFFJAyTqif
                        aUjYEQqcszKcbvf/XvriNcjHlk3kM8AwaQMePngxJatY3rlYWbykZhmwdqBgWrknRkjr5GAWVPEU
                        Q3aRlfbRYi66LV0UeGrzkinV2z5pwmBNxqc9GNnWMsvq0sWyF0BLSDY7yIz4HZVaeySytmZC21fI
                        PktCIfv+NRmOtFznkg3utX27Iwmc4kYGfeBXxmPMLOIkhf3dItOtV/8KNA4jW5dJNxnOEXiVXEV+
                        FJZbeAIet4wBvAfQb6QXcrfuwBp2kCmoYtmObH5Y+AgEf5KxPiGb1kLX
                      </ds:SignatureValue>
                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>
                                MIIExDCCAywCCQC0bmU6MB8PuTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBozELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEgxEDAOBgNV
                                BAgTB0J1ZW5kaWExDzANBgNVBAcTBk1ha2F0aTEeMBwGA1UEChMVT2JlcnRodXIgVGVjaG5vbG9n
                                aWVzMSEwHwYDVQQLExhSZXNlYXJjaCBhbmQgRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxCzAJBgNVBAMTAk9UMSEwHwYJ
                                KoZIhvcNAQkBFhJlbWFpbEBvYmVydGh1ci5jb20wHhcNMTQxMDI1MDgzMzE5WhcNMTUxMDI1MDgz
                                MzE5WjCBozELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEgxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0J1ZW5kaWExDzANBgNVBAcTBk1ha2F0aTEe
                                MBwGA1UEChMVT2JlcnRodXIgVGVjaG5vbG9naWVzMSEwHwYDVQQLExhSZXNlYXJjaCBhbmQgRGV2
                                ZWxvcG1lbnQxCzAJBgNVBAMTAk9UMSEwHwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhJlbWFpbEBvYmVydGh1ci5jb20w
                                ggGiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBjwAwggGKAoIBgQDEaJeQaBruoMMG5LEdLc6D4aQq/4IXc6tk
                                kbEyO+2o3Ey3dU/WFSS7DNy86DKPWTG0VKinpFinwic+Be+A36K/eei8wyyv2YuhI1UuKWPsvmkV
                                mb/klra899jKvid1Jd0oMG8ViQGkpveYdoAfg5IR9k2NSgV1cn3ab26CmwwIpbDuPcMhW0bEXxG+
                                El67hrLQqpDjIuWRpbxs5prBdG4V79NrR6Pu1goLq9FmHsmKujPAu1gSnNmx61rab8zzVcEG19Fd
                                huG7ysilzDSeo2YTKs7Lzwp4Zu94T+IJYHYrV4iiB4jVLO7IQCUKB3T4y+9VYHI1fhasRGB1t8eR
                                CScsKg8IvtMMwjvKv4XK0EdBaLADzvpRVGAiV1hlo3sJ+D+tr/gkJ/ElVjC/90gIVxESwg5XQtPG
                                kQImde6GDZquEcT5URyvkq/WuMu+3J4NUSMpHDXeel2R8UkiSXs5ONxRyT3Ai3IjXUFhO9EGjFpe
                                eM1gqSYx3l6DyPSBF1rKHmkCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAYEAaDkvLk/tzIMJA/3q2zJL
                                M+N5cPc+OVG8kPJK3aMInXciZRrY+uSyTflVaOpJJu038fN07kMzQePDyRJQENOZK0JsDz2bX1h5
                                6Z03b34/UdgFR5z3NC++iQNbBFaXjsfcAo45UgEgn7wPdqXQ8bdViHakmCMG43vPzLgp2ZSK0GMt
                                Pt1Q2qnbWz04Gkjog284RZZ4mpxSA3g8sVypoDTjw3HJhNRCPjq+tTXkOqWK4nNJH5tbwqq9uUjJ
                                6nTISN5WJ3OIvdLejPNmjMBBcaGVmFkGIBqlfyMZ+SuJiqMJfW/Ccqf640U3tyZDJNeTxMmaqerE
                                mnihf+sIdPf2RfwbdBPiHdLmmU65yi89b6Bz
                              </ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </ds:Signature>
            </ns:ParentNode>
        </ns:Request>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I validate signature using cxf? I saw an implementation of WSPolicy and WSS4JInterceptors and it think it is not fit for this situation because the request doesn't have `<wsse:Security>` tag. Any thoughts are very much welcome.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WS-Security standard mandates that XML Signature must be in the security header of the request (and not in the SOAP Body as per your example). So your best bet is to grab the SOAP Body (e.g. in a SOAP Handler), and use the Apache Santuario API to validate the signature yourself. Here is some sample code that shows you how to do the latter:

https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureDOMTest.java

Colm.

Comment: thank you very much to your answer @Colm, is there an article/documentation that states the prerequisites of your soap signature structure before considering using WSS4JInterceptor or XML Policy in cxf?

Comment: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/os/wss-SOAPMessageSecurity-v1.1.1-os.html